# Changing a DB View dynamically according the current user-group

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

we are currently digging into Amazon Redshift and testing different functionalities.

One of our basic requirements is that we will define different user groups which in turn will be granted access to different views.

One way to go about this would be to implement one view seperately for each user-group. However, since we have a lot of user-groups that share almost the exact same need for information, I'm looking for a way to implement this more dynamically in Redshift.

For instance, let's say I have a user group called **users_london** and another one called **users_berlin**. Both will have access to a view called **v_employee_master_data** which contains the columns **employee_name**, **employee_job_title** and **employee_city**. 
Both groups share the same scope of information with one exception - the column **employee_city**.

In essence, the view should be pre-filtered for a certain value in the column **employee_city** according to the currently logged-in user-group.

In SQL - something like this:

For the usergroup **users_london**:

```
SELECT * FROM v_employee_master_data WHERE employee_city = 'London';
```

For the usergroup **users_berlin**:

```
SELECT * FROM v_employee_master_data WHERE employee_city = 'Berlin';
```

Now to make the connection back to Amazon Redshift. Does the underlying DB runtime provide an out-of-the-box functionality to somehow catch the currently logged user-group as a form of *global variable* and alter the SQL-statement according to the value of that variable?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do:

1. get current user

`select current_user`

2. find what group it belongs to

`select groname from pg_group where current_user_id = any(grolist);`

3. Extract city and capitalize it:

`select initcap(substring(groname from 'users_(.*)'))   from pg_group where current_user_id = any(grolist);`

Now you have your city based on the "user".  So just inject it in the view

`... WHERE employee_city = initcap(substring(groname from 'users_(.*)') ...`